# How to read file time stamps in a Directory

Tags: linux, file-io, timestamp, stat

I want to read the stat of all the files within a directory in C. (linux: Fedora)

i have declared this structure:

```
struct stat st = {0};
```

Then I check for the existence of the directory.

```
if(stat("/home/gadre/Source",&st) == -1)
{
    status = mkdir("/home/gadre/Source", 0777);             
}
syslog(LOG_INFO, "Source Directory stage completed\n");
```

where stat is:

```
struct stat {
    dev_t     st_dev;     /* ID of device containing file */
    ino_t     st_ino;     /* inode number */
    mode_t    st_mode;    /* protection */
    nlink_t   st_nlink;   /* number of hard links */
    uid_t     st_uid;     /* user ID of owner */
    gid_t     st_gid;     /* group ID of owner */
    dev_t     st_rdev;    /* device ID (if special file) */
    off_t     st_size;    /* total size, in bytes */
    blksize_t st_blksize; /* blocksize for file system I/O */
    blkcnt_t  st_blocks;  /* number of 512B blocks allocated */
    time_t    st_atime;   /* time of last access */
    time_t    st_mtime;   /* time of last modification */
    time_t    st_ctime;   /* time of last status change */
};
```

now once i enter the directory I would want to check the last modification time st_mtime
of each file.

Any ideas what data structure I should be using...should store the fd in a list first and then iterate over it checking... what is the efficient approach.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic approach is looping without any list like containers,

1. Open fullpath of your dir `dp = opendir(fullpath))` and get the directory pointer
2. Loop by reading `dp` like this `while ( (dirp = readdir(dp)) != NULL )`
3. Get the file names from the dirent structure `dirp->d_name`
4. Construct a new full path for the filepahts i.e. smth like this `filepath = fullpath + "/" + dirp->d_name`
5. and finally perform `lstat` to get the time-stamp info

P.S. I would prefer to use `lstat` because one of the files in your directory might be a symbolic link, in this case `lstat` will return the timestamp of the symbolic link itself and not the timestamp of the file to which it points to

Comment: hi, that worked thanks, any idea how I can verify if the file was upadated after a previous access.

For eg:
23-09-2014  File was updated (modified) so  st_atime, st_mtime would have changed to 23-09-2014. but st_ctime not..because inode information would remain same.

on 25-09-2014 the file was modified and hence atime and mtime were changed.

But, for a program reading this stat information on 26-09-2014 how should it know that it was modified

Comment: good to know that is was a solution, then probably you can accept the answer. Regarding to your second question, as much as I remember `st_atim` is the last access time of file data, i.e. it indicates when it has been read, and `st_mtim` is the last modification time of file data, i.e. when it has been written. So if you are opening the file only with write attribute is should modify only the `st_mtim`.